# Multiplying an array by a number

Tags: arrays, clojure

I've been writing out a function in Clojure that would take a row of a 2d array and then multiples the values in it by a single value. I have the index to get the specific row and the value to multiply the row with in another array.

The function will return the array, that has now got values multipled by the single value.

Here's the code:

```
(def twod-array [[3.1 0.0023  0.35]
                [0.21 0.00353 8.13]])

(def iandv [1 3.1])

(defn array-multiply [iandv twod-array]
(
      let [array-row (nth twod-array (nth iandv 0))]
      (map * [array-row] [(nth iandv 1)])
)
```

The let gets the array row and then it will return the row with the values inside multiplied with the value of the "index and value" array.

This has the closest I've gotten using the examples with the clojure.doc website and I'm getting a ClassCastException of the following:

```
ClassCastException clojure.lang.PersistentVector cannot be cast to java.lang.Number  clojure.lang.Numbers.multiply (Numbers.java:148)
```

I've been looking at map vector and other map functions but I haven't been able to find a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is somewhat hard to read, but basically, you're trying to multiply a number and a vector, that doesn't work.

```
(defn array-multiply [iandv twod-array]
  (let [array-row (nth twod-array (nth iandv 0))]
    (map * array-row [(nth iandv 1)])))
```

works since `array-row` already is a vector.

Comment: This will only multiply the first element of `array-row` since `(nth iandv 1)` is only one element long and map will stop after any collection is exhausted. I would suggest doing it like this: `(map #(* % (nth iandv 1)) array-row)`

Comment: @Delphi1024 I tried that line of code and it worked. Tested the answer too and it was correct. I had tried using a placeholder yesterday but I hadn't used the hash so it didn't work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

more clojurish way could look something like this:

```
(defn array-multiply [[row mul] twod-array]
  (update twod-array row #(mapv (partial * mul) %)))

user> (array-multiply iandv twod-array)
;;=> [[3.1 0.0023 0.35] [0.651 0.010943000000000001 25.203000000000003]]
```